# libgdx gradle обновился и теперь не работает

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, update

Android Studio оповестило об обновлении, согласился, обновил, теперь проект не компилится.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня была копия проекта(запасную ещё одну сделал), обновляю gradle, обновление успешно, а после та же самая ошибка, что на скриншоте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй изменить в Gradle https на http
и добавить jcenter()

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.1.0'
    }
}
```

Comment: я не могу найти где это :(

Comment: В Android studio, слева во вкладке Project, в списке найди - Gradle Scripts,  далее выбери и открой - build.gradle (Project Reaction Teacher), там вверху найди эти строки что я написал и вставь - jcenter()